# Where to put @SWG\Definition to be reused with Swagger-PHP and Nelmio API-DOC Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, swagger-php, nelmioapidocbundle

I'd like to write a @SWG\Definition somewhere and refer to it in the @SWG\Schema in @SWG\Response annotations for multiple REST API actions in my Symfony 3 application. I'm using the dev-master version of Nelmio's api-doc-bundle but I can seem to find anything that suggests where that definition should go. The Swagger-PHP docs urge not repeating if possible and I'd like to follow that recommendation. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Typical...  Finally break down and ask then figure out a solution shortly after...

I found that I can preload the documentation data in Symfony's app/config/config.yml.

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        definitios:
            Error: 
                type: object
                properties:
                    success:
                        type: boolean
                        example: false
                    error:
                        type: string
                        example: message
```

Now I can use something like this in all my REST actions

```
/**
 *  @API\Operation(
 *     ...
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="default",
 *         description="Failure",
 *         @SWG\Schema(ref="#definitions/Error")
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Trouble with this approach is that there doesn't seem to be a way to trigger generation of definitions for entities with @API\Model().